# REGEXP_REPLACE in redshift

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

My input value is a string formatted like '2.990.00', I want to convert it to be like '2990.00', i.e. to remove the thousands separator. I tried the below but no luck.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('2.990.00','(\\d)(\\d{1}).(\\d{2})','\\1\\2.\\3');
```

Comment: Is the last digits after the last dot (.)  always 2 characters?

Comment: Or did you mean like this?   `SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR('2.990.00',1,5), '.', '');`

Comment: Input : 2.990.00
Output : 2990.00

I want remove first dot

Comment: I improved the language to emphasize that you want to remove the thousands separator. Avoid using phrases like "thanks" and "any help appreciated".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE('2.990.00','(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', '\1\2.\3')
```

Comment: do you have more detail on what is not working ? Is it a syntax issue ? I think the regex and replacement rule is correct as far as I tested.

Comment: try to replace \d by [0-9] maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed

select REGEXP_REPLACE('2.990.00','(\d).(\d{1})(\d{2})','\1\2\3')

Thanks